# About new[][] and initializing classes in array

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CType{
private:
    int val;
public:
    CType(): val(0){}
    CType(int x): val(x){}
    void setVal(int x){ val = x; }
    ~CType(){ cout << val << " is destructed." << endl;} 
};

int main(){
    // CType *t = new CType[10](10); // -1-
    CType (*t)[10] = new CType[10][10]; // -2-
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; ++j){
            t[i][j].setVal(10 * i + j);
        }
    }
    delete[] t;
    return 0;
}
```

The above code is a sample I wrote to test new[][] and whether it is possible to initialize instances in dynamic array. My question is:

1. I intended to create an array of 10 `CType` instances with `val` initialized to 10. But this line cannot pass compilation. I have to add a default constructor with no parameter and `CType *t = new CType[10]`. Is there any way to create an array of instances and invoke constructors with some parameters?
2. I got puzzled by `new int[10][10]` which intuitively creates an 10x10 2D array. But I cannot find any official material defining the behavior of `new int[][]` or `new int[][][]` etc. Why does `new int[10][10]` have return type `int (*)[10]` rather than `int**` or `int[10][10]`?

BTW, if I write `CType (*t)[10] = new CType[10][10](10)`, I'll got a compilation error reading `A.cpp:13:39: sorry, unimplemented: cannot initialize multi-dimensional array with initializer`. Funny, **g++** says SORRY.

---

**Update**

I'm using **g++**. But I also tested the code on **VS2010**. It passed compilation and output the same result as it did in **g++**.

The variable `t` in `CType (*t)[10]` is a pointer which points to an array of 10 `CType` instances, not an array of 10 `CType` pointers. So `t + 1` points to the place `sizeof(CType) * 10` bytes away after `t`.

The output of my code reveals that the destruct order of `delete[] t` is 99 to 0. The last element of `t + 9` is destructed first.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Do you really have to use C arrays ? take a look to STL containers : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/

Comment: [This FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/) covers more than you would ever want to know about arrays in C++, including fancy ASCII art explaining the behavior of various flavors of multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Default constructors never have parameters. That's why they're the default.

Comment: @user3134405 No, I don't. I'm familiar with STL, but at this time I just want to better understand the `new` operator and the constructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to create an array of instances and invoke constructors with some parameters?

There is since C++11:

```
CType* t = new CType[10] {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10};
// ...
delete[] t;
```

But in general, you are far better of with vectors in C++:

```
std::vector<CType> t(10);
// ...
// no need to delete anything manually!
```

> I cannot find any official material defining the behavior of `new int[][]` or `new int[][][]` etc.

5.3.4 [expr.new] §5 says:

> When the allocated object is an array [...], the *new-expression* yields a pointer to the initial element (if any) of the array.
>
> Note: both `new int` and `new int[10]` have type `int*` and the type of `new int[i][10]` is `int (*)[10]`

---

> Why does `new int[10][10]` have return type `int (*)[10]` rather than `int**`

It couldn't be `int**`, because then a simple `delete[]` wouldn't be enough.

> or `int[10][10]`?

Because `int[10][10]` is not a pointer, but `new` always returns a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no way to provide a parenthesed initializer in a new-expression of an array type. Don't use legacy C arrays if you can help it. Standard containers provide a superior alternative.
2. This is specified by the standard. A new-expression that allocates an array returns a pointer to the first element of the array (5.3.4/1). `new int[N][4][5][6]` creates an array of N elements, each one of type int[4][5][6]. The pointer to the first element of the array will be returned. It will be of type `int(*)[4][5][6]`, not `int****` or somesuch. It is easy to understand if you accept that there are **no** multidimensional arrays in C++, only arrays of arrays. An element of `int x[2][3]` has type `int[3]`, not `int`. Words like `pointer to the first element` do not automatically generalize to `pointer to the first element of the first element` etc.